# Trying to submit a formik form to an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik

This is probably a simple fix but I'm at a loss since I'm still learning this. I built an action addTenant() that normally would take in the state and pass it along to dispatch a post API call that looks like this

```
export const addTenant = (tenant) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/Tenant/", tenant)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_TENANT,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err)); // error log
};
```

Now I switched my form to using formik because I changed up my model which led to it having a nested object and I felt formik may make it easier. The issue is I can't seem to pass the values to the function properly to fire off the addTenant action which then intern should raise the ADD_TENANT case in my reducer while also setting submitting back to false while resetting the form.

Below is the code in question. Any help would be appreciated cause I'm stumped.

```
export class TenantForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      domain_url: "",
      schema_name: "",
      name: "",
      config: [
        {
          date: "",
          tenant_description: "",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    addTenant: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { domain_url, schema_name, name, config } = this.state;
    const show = {
      domain_url,
      schema_name,
      name,
      config,
    };
    this.props.addTenant(tenant);
  };

  render() {
    const {
     domain_url,
     schema_name,
     name,
     config,
    } = this.state;

    const ClientSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      domain_url: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client URL header is required"),
      schema_name: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client db name is required"),
      name: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client name is required"),
    });

    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            domain_url: "",
            schema_name: "",
            name: "",
            config: [
              {
                date: "",
                tenant_description: "",
              },
            ],
          }}
          // validationSchema={ClientSchema} this is breaking submit
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
            setSubmitting(true);
            values.domain_url = values.domain_url + ".localhost";
            this.addTenant(values);
            resetForm();
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            status,
            touched,
            handleBlur,
            handleChange,
            isSubmitting,
            setFieldValue,
            handleSubmit,
            props,
          }) => (
            <FormGroup>
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <legend>
                  <strong>Create</strong> Tenant
                </legend>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you directly perform  `this.props.addTenant(values);` in onSubmit inside Formik?

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
            setSubmitting(true);
            values.domain_url = values.domain_url + ".localhost";
            this.props.addTenant(values);
            resetForm();
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
```

Comment: tried that, the case never gets called, and the setSubmitting stays set to true and doesn't continue along with the function

Comment: Are you sure you have addTenant on your props?

Comment: I couldn't tell you if i did or not. i added this.props.addTenant(values) to the onSubmit  within <Formik />  up before the function I have static propTypes = {
    addTenant: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

Comment: Is there any errors thrown? Can  you show how you made connection with addTenant?

Comment: wait never mind I had a spelling error, it's sending it but I'm getting a 400 bad request from it.

Comment: that was it. I need the props but I had a spelling mistake with how I was exporting it. thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: You rock Dipesh KC, you've helped me out a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***handleSubmit*** function.
It's a Formik native function, you can pass **as a property to any children** in your Form.
Children component/s can execute ***handleSubmit*** in order to trigger form submission.

```
   return (
    <div className='filters-transaction'>
      <Formik>
        {({ values, handleReset, handleSubmit, errors }) => (
          <Form>
            <div className='filters-transaction__filters'>
              <DatePicker
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                />
            </div>
            </Form>
            </Formik>
            </div>
```

...then in your children component...

```
return (<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>)
```